# When did people decide that all caps means the writer is shouting?

Tags: cultural-history, language

Nowadays, writing in all caps tends to indicate that the writer is shouting.

FOR EXAMPLE IF I TYPE LIKE THIS PEOPLE EQUATE THIS TO SHOUTING.

My understanding from cursory googling is that letters were originally only in one case and a separate case was developed later, with most people considering the first case to be capitalized and the second, newer case to be lowercase. Newspaper headlines and advertisements sometimes lapsed into all caps, but I can't find any indication that the all caps typography was meant to be interpreted as literally shouting the headline at people.

When did people start making the distinction that using the default capitalized letters means the writer is shouting (assuming this practice is old enough that "default" has any meaning)?

Comment: It goes back to the days of bulletin boards. [This article](https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling) suggests circa 1984.

Comment: @Schwern Speak softly and carry a big joystick! ;-)

Comment: @sempaiscuba I saw that with my googling, but I dismissed it. Kind of figured something this intuitive and simplistic had to predate the 1980's. Maybe that is the answer, I'll give the answers some time.

Comment: More applicable on English.SE than here?

Comment: I had the feeling that the use of all caps for shouting in comic books is older, but I can not find any examples.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, it's not necessarily english, I think. Any other language with capital letters is OK.

Comment: Depends on context, really. It can also mean a voice that sounds like a coffin closing (NOW WHERE DID I PUT MY SCYTHE?), but which is also making people rather uncomfortable. ;-)

Comment: The questioner should probably note that they are looking for a computing based answer if they are.  Despite the accepted answer, which provides the electronic history answer, my _suspicion_ is that it was likely used as such in written text, e.g. hand-written letters, long in advance of its use digitally.  I wonder if any scripts for plays did so...?

Comment: @Baldrickk No, to clarify, I want the earliest time in written language, it just appears from the answers and the surface research I've done that it originated in the 80's on computers. I'd like to see it traced back further, if you find something earlier I'd love to see it.

Comment: And in related news: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmiuEwJUDR0

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GGMG I'm no expert ;)  But it might be worth cross-posting to https://literature.stackexchange.com/  they might have a better knowledge of literature.  All we would need is one example of a raised voice written in all-caps...

Comment: It becomes a convention for meaning rudeness, loudness, shouting. I found a link which tells history of that  convention https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling

Comment: NO IT IS POLITE TO REPLY TO A CONVERSATION IN CAPS LOCKS. WHY WOULD ANYONE THINK THAT WRITING LIKE -=THIS=- IS NOT OK... IS IT AN "UNECESSARY AMPLIFICATION OF TONE" COMPARED TO OTHER WRITERS OF THE WEB CONVERSATION, WHO USE NORMAL SIZED WRITNG? WHY DO YOU THINK AMPLIFIED LETTERS IS ASSOCIATED WITH AMPLIFIED TONE OF VOICE? WHY DOES THE LETTER P SYMBOLIZE ;P ... ITS OBVIOUS WHEN YOU LEARN TO MEASURE INTERNET WRITING AND SUBTELTIES. WHY CAPITALS ARE SHOUTING.... capitals became raised tone of attention when adults started to write messages in all capitals.

Comment: REMEMBER THAT CAPS LOCK IS CRUISE CONTROL FOR LOUD AND AWESOME!

Comment: Cartoonist Mike Reed had a Flame Warrior known as AA CAPS.  This came along about 10 years after caps were used to convey yelling.  https://www.politicsforum.org/allcaps/

Comment: There [a whole Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps) for it, including *"With the advent of the bulletin board system, or BBS, and later the Internet, typing messages in all caps became closely identified with "shouting" or attention-seeking behavior, and may be considered rude."*

Comment: @DevSolar - it can also mean the speaker is hungry, e.g. I COULD JUST MURDER A CURRY.

Comment: Also see Terry Pratchett's Discworld, where Death speaks with uppercase letters cut to stone, and The Wicked + The Divine comics by Kieron Gillen, where every reincarnated god speaks in different color.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The tradition of all caps denoting shouting arose from typesetting of printed publications.

The 6 September 1958 [Bookseller: The Organ of the Book Trade](https://books.google.com/books?id=hNsaAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22ALL%20CAPS%22%20%22shouting%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=1958%20%22all%20caps%22) says:

> It [a 16 page list of books] picks out titles in red, and speaks moderately with large-size upper and lower-case letters rather than shouting with all caps. The effect is pleasing to anybody in a contemplative mood.

And more than a century before that, in "The Dutchman Who Had the  Small Pox" in the [17 April 1856 Yorkville [South Carolina] Enquirer](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026925/1856-04-17/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1789&index=3&rows=20&words=capital+letter+shouted&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1943&proxtext=shouting++capital+letters&y=0&x=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) and many other newspapers:

> This time he shouted it out in capital letters

Likewise, "The Sore Grievance of John Wellspanked" in [6 May 1871 The Shamrock](https://books.google.com/books?id=fuARAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA474&dq=%22CAPITAL%20letters%22%20%22yelling%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE9t2yk5jXAhWKh1QKHRQcC6AQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22CAPITAL%20letters%22%20%22yelling%22&f=false) says:

> "TWELVE shillings and SEVEN pence?" roared my aunt in the biggest capital letters

Similarly, "Imaginary London" in the [June 1873 Belgravia](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHdJAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA216&dq=yelled%20%22capital%20letters%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5x7uxlZjXAhXT0J8KHQjGDpkQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=yelled%20%22capital%20letters%22&f=false) says:

> '...Here, cab, *cab*, CAB!' The last monosyllable was a yell to which only capital letters can give due impression

Even more clearly, the 1880 [The Standard speaker and elocutionist](https://books.google.com/books?id=TioCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA188&dq=%22capital%20letters%22%20shouting&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm-eWVwpHXAhWFSCYKHeUvApkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22capital%20letters%22%20shouting&f=false) has a section of the book titled:

> SHOUTING STYLE
>
> This will be seldom needed throughout an entire piece, but wherever the words imply calling, or commanding, it will be in keeping with the words to employ it. As examples note the following selections marked in CAPITAL letters as the appropriate place for shouting emphasis.

The 1880 book then goes on for pages with examples from literature of all caps being used for shouting.

However, the earliest indication of a standard that I have found so far is from the 1852 [Singing for Schools and Congregations: A Grammar of Vocal Music](https://books.google.com/books?id=XDNkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22capital%20letters%22%20loud&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKsNL9mJjXAhUqs1QKHfJDDp0Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22capital%20letters%22%20loud&f=false):

> It is proposed that-
> CAPITAL LETTERS, in printing, or double lines under the word in writing, should distinguish words to be sung *louder*

Another clear example is from the 1860 [Elementary books for Catholic schools](https://books.google.com/books?id=BtQDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22help%22%20%22in%20capital%20letters%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV45DKgKDXAhUC5CYKHbAnC_UQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22help%22%20%22in%20capital%20letters%22&f=false), explaining how to read stories with italics and all caps:

> when you come to a word printed in this way [italics], you must read it more distinctly than the other words.
>
> > ...And began to scream out as loud as he could,| "HELP!HELP!HELP!"
>
> Observe these last three words: they are printed in *capital letters* letters because they are very important.  The man cried, "help!" very loudly.

Comment: Yes - the convention of using capital letters to represent shouting/emphasis existed in print long before it was ever used online :-)

Comment: I expect caps as shouting really came about shortly after the invention of the printing press.

Comment: It's notable that the examples given are all humorously self-referential (the self-reference presumably being precisely what made it possible to find them) and the humour of lamp-shading the convention depends on the convention being well-established.

Comment: Adam West and Burt Ward were demonstrating this as early as 1966 on prime time TV.

Comment: Can you also please elaborate on why journal names were written in ALL CAPS in the early 20th century? Like [this one](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01353a027) - "THE REACTIVE FORM OF GLUCOSE OXIME" Why aren't they considered to be shouting?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I think it was considered shouting.  For example a 1957 source says "One of the problems of layout of a publisher's list, whether it be a general catalogue or a piece of seasonal sales-promotion, is to give sufficient emphasis to each title without creating the effect of shouting everything at the top of the voice. Most publishers use capital letters for each title announcement..."  https://books.google.com/books?id=sxFPAAAAIAAJ&q=title+capital+letters+%22shouting%22&dq=title+capital+letters+%22shouting%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVifXZxqXaAhXHuFkKHaqsCq0Q6AEIJzAA

Answer (score 179):

## SOMETIME AFTER 1984

[BICAMERAL SCRIPT HAS BEEN AROUND FOR CENTURIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Bicameral_script) THOUGH THE RULES FOR ITS USE HAVE ONLY SOLIDIFIED IN THE LAST FEW HUNDRED YEARS. WHILE PRINTED MATERIAL WAS ABLE TO USE BOTH UPPER AND LOWER CASE, THE NEED FOR EFFICIENCY IN TELEGRAPH COMMUNICATIONS MEANT THERE WAS AN ERA WHEN ALL ELECTRONIC COMMUNICATION WAS IN ALL-CAPS FROM THE EARLY 19TH CENTURY TO THE EARLY 1980S.

EARLY COMPUTERS WERE NOT ABLE TO DISPLAY LOWER CASE, OR DID NOT BY DEFAULT. WHEN PERSONAL COMPUTERS CAME ALONG, AND SCREEN RESOLUTIONS WERE HIGH ENOUGH, THEIR BROADER USE CREATED A NEED FOR LOWER CASE. THIS WOULD BE SOLIDIFIED WHEN CHARACTER SET STANDARDS SUCH AS [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) AND [LATIN-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) WERE WIDELY ADOPTED FOR LATIN SCRIPTS.

NEW REPUBLIC PUBLISHED AN ARTICLE [*HOW CAPITAL LETTERS BECAME INTERNET CODE FOR YELLING*](https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling) WHICH CONTAINS MANY REFERENCES TO POSSIBILITIES, BUT NO DEFINITIVE ANSWER. IT NOTES THAT ALL-CAPS HAS BEEN USED BACK INTO ANTIQUITY FOR EMPHASIS, BUT THERE IS NO CONSENSUS FOR WHEN IT BECAME WIDELY UNDERSTOOD TO BE YELLING, AND IN PARTICULAR VULGAR SHOUTING.

WE CAN PUT SOME BOUNDARIES ON THE DATE. [THIS THREAD FROM USENET BACK IN 1984](https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21msg/net.flame/VbghoeOfwyI/E2mClWj2GV8J) PEOPLE ARE STILL DEBATING HOW BEST TO ADD EMPHASIS TO TEXT. THAT THIS DISCUSSION WAS HAPPENING INDICATES THE MATTER WAS STILL NOT SETTLED. VARIOUS THINGS ARE SUGGESTED INCLUDING...

- ALL-CAPS
- *ASTERISKS*
- S P A C I N G
- SwItChInG cAsE (WHICH I REMEMBER AS A MaD hAxOr THING)

T H A T   T H R E A D   I S   A M A Z I N G, *I'D SUGGEST YOU READ IT*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134044/discussion-on-answer-by-schwern-when-did-people-decide-that-all-caps-means-the-w).

Answer (score 20):

In the computer world, the use of ALL CAPS to mean yelling or shouting goes back to the days of [Bulletin board system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system) (BBS). The use seems to [go back to at least 1984](https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling), and was one of three ways of emphasising text that had developed at that point

(things like **bold** or *italic* weren't available as options for text emphasis in those days).

- CAPITAL LETTERS made text look "louder" (a.k.a. "shouting" or
  "yelling", depending on which side of the Atlantic you were from)
- Using *asterisks* as *sparklers* to emphasise words.
- S p a c i n g  words out.

Comment: You missed colors. By the late 80s many BBSes supported ANSI color codes and even flashing. I once (in my youth) went a bit overboard with all caps, bright red, flashing text on a BBS. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: @ToddWilcox That's true for the late 80s, but back in 1984 very few of us had colour monitors (it was just 3 years after IBM had introduced the CGA), so using colours for emphasis back then would have been pointless. Most people just couldn't see them!

Comment: The advantage of using upper case over other forms of indicating emphasis is simplicity, speed, and availability compared to bolding, italics, or color. Every keyboard has uppercase, and the simplest monitor can display it. And in the emotional state  in which you are likely to be "raising your voice" to let the rest of the world know your humble opinion, you don't want to take the time required for those other mechanisms.

Comment: Color displays were not rare in 1984, except among IBM PC compatibles. Color TVs were widely used as displays for personal computers.

Comment: It goes back to 1983 at least.  I used to visit BBS systems then, and at the time, people who had computers that displayed lower case used to mock people who had computers that didn't for "yelling all the time".

Comment: Note that while the Apple ][ computer did color at that time, the way it was implemented, colored text was difficult or impossible.  (Two pixels next to each other appeared white.  See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_graphics#Color_on_the_Apple_II).)

Comment: @StevenBurnap I started using BBS back in 1982/83 from a tty terminal attached to a college PDP-11 computer. Everything was upper-case. By 1984, I was mainly using a "home-brew" 8-bit micro computer and normal-case text. Personally, I didn't see any comments about "yelling" in upper-case until about 1985/86. I've had limited Internet access this week (staying in one of the UK's "not-spots"), but I did manage a couple of quick searches and I didn't see any confirmed references for the practice before 1984 (hence my "goes back to at least 1984 ...").

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a source, just memory.  I got an Apple ][ on Christmas my senior year, and very quickly went online.  I graduated in 1983.  In particular, I remember the Apple guys mocking the C64 guys for this.  Obviously my memory could be confused about the date.  This would have been San Diego area BBS systems, and so maybe it was a local thing at that point?

Comment: @sempaiscuba - "1984 [...] was just 3 years after IBM had introduced the CGA" -- while this is true, it's also just 3 years after IBM introduced the PC. CGA was an option on the very first model of PC, and this was more popular (at least among home users) due to the fact that it could be used with a TV rather than a more expensive monitor required by the monochrome system.

Comment: @Jules The original IBM CGA cards did have a connector for an add-on RF modulator unit installed inside the computer case, but no such device was ever offered by IBM. Certainly, none of the home users I knew in 1984 were using IBM PCs connected to a TV.

Comment: Don't forget the [PCjr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PCjr), which did color, though no one bought them

Comment: @Jules It probably also was more popular with home users because IBM's alternative, MDA, didn't do graphics *at all*. MDA was pure text, 80x25 characters, with some special attributes. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter#Description. While you needed CGA to do graphics, MDA excelled at text, which CGA handled much more poorly. Compare the PC Magazine June 1983 quote at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Monochrome_Display_Adapter#Competing_adapters.

Answer (score 17):

There's a comment at https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21msg/net.flame/VbghoeOfwyI/E2mClWj2GV8J :

> Capitalizing whole words gives the impression that you're shouting.

So the usage was already current in 1984.

Also, the mixed case suggestion isn't serious

http://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/documents/advice/hints-net-write.html

Comment: Excessive capitalisation hurts the eyes reading it, just like shouting hurts the ears hearing it.

Comment: I hope the mixed case suggestion is serious.  Mixed case is much easier to read. Mixed case means that letters are capitalized according to grammatical conventions.

Comment: Is this in response to @Schwern's answer by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

It is human nature to equate larger than normal characters with volume. It is also human nature to equate an exclamation point with shouting, just as it is human nature to equate a question mark with confusion. Whether it is a tweet, or whether it is a passage in an old book, the association is the same. This is true? This is true! THIS IS TRUE!!!! (see what I mean?)

Therefore, the association of all caps with shouting began with 
[mixed case alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case). It became prevalent with computers, as the need to go through editors and publishers to get one's written word out to the public was eliminated, and thus the safeguards for proper diction were also eliminated.

Comment: Our understanding of exclamation and question marks are not human nature; they're learned behaviour. Nor do we always equate larger characters with volume. For example, we don't interpret headings as shouting, despite the larger font.